# Parse twitter-cldr-js formatted number back into integer or float?

Tags: javascript, localization, cldr

Is there any easy way to do reverse of:

```
// include twitter_cldr/es.js
var fmt = new TwitterCldr.DecimalFormatter();
fmt.format(1337); // "1.337"
```

i.e. parse "1.337" back to integer with value of 1337?

The solution should work for any [twitter-cldr-js](https://github.com/twitter/twitter-cldr-js) supported locale.

I am not looking for parseInt / parseFloat, as it does not handle all possible locales.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After two days of trial & error I've found it impossible to do this using twitter-cldr-js and turned to [Globalize](https://github.com/jquery/globalize) instead, which does the job very neatly.